# How move custom route outside of server.js in jsonServer

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

In `server.js`, I am using `json-server`. I want to move

```
server.get('/api/1.0/searchDoc', (req, res) => {
    const searchType = req.query['searchType'];
    const searchValue = req.query['searchValue'];
    res.status(200).jsonp({searchType, searchValue});
});
```

to `route.js` then import in `server.js`. How do I achieve it?

Full code

```
// json server
const jsonServer = require('json-server');
// create server
const server = jsonServer.create();

// data as router
const allDocData = require('../response.json');
const searchDocData = require('../searchResponse.json');
const dataObj = {
    'mockResponse': allDocData,
    'searchDocData': searchDocData
};

const router = jsonServer.router(dataObj);

// mid-ware
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

// package.json uses port 4000
const port = 4000;

// live before router
// e.g. http://localhost:4000/api/1.0/searchDoc/?searchType='customerId'&searchValue='1234'
server.get('/api/1.0/searchDoc', (req, res) => {
    const searchType = req.query['searchType'];
    const searchValue = req.query['searchValue'];
    res.status(200).jsonp({searchType, searchValue});
});

// use mid-ware
server.use(middlewares);
// use data
server.use(router);

// user body parser
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
// use mid-ware
server.use(middlewares);

// use router
server.use(router);

// listen
server.listen(port);
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? `www.js`

```
const JSONServer = require('jsonserver')

function build() {
 const server = JSONServer.create()

 server.get('/api/1.0/searchDoc', (req, res) => {
    const searchType = req.query['searchType'];
    const searchValue = req.query['searchValue'];
    res.status(200).jsonp({searchType, searchValue});
 });

 return server
}

module.exports = build
```

And on another file `index.js` for example

```
const build = require('./www.js')
const server = build()
// use mid-ware
server.use(middlewares);
// use data
server.use(router);

// user body parser
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
// use mid-ware
server.use(middlewares);

// use router
server.use(router);

// listen
server.listen(port);
```

you can if you just return it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways this could be achieved - another approach would be to inject the `server` instance into the `route.js` module which would enable your app's routing concern to be extracted as:

**route.js**

```
/* 
Define default module function that configures apps routing for the specified 
server instance
*/
module.exports = function(server) {

    server.get('/api/1.0/searchDoc', (req, res) => {
        const searchType = req.query['searchType'];
        const searchValue = req.query['searchValue'];
        res.status(200).jsonp({searchType, searchValue});
    });
}
```

**server.js**

```
const jsonServer = require('json-server');

/* 
Import default module function from route.js module. We'll assing this
function to the configureRoutes variable and call it in the server.js when
needed. This import assumes route.js exists in the same directory of this
source file 
*/
const configureRoutes = require('./route.js');

const server = jsonServer.create();
const allDocData = require('../response.json');
const searchDocData = require('../searchResponse.json');
const dataObj = {
    'mockResponse': allDocData,
    'searchDocData': searchDocData
};

const router = jsonServer.router(dataObj);
const middlewares = jsonServer.defaults();

const port = 4000;

/*
Call configureRoutes() to configure routes on your server instance via the
new route.js module
*/
configureRoutes(server);

server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);
server.use(jsonServer.bodyParser);
server.use(middlewares);
server.use(router);

server.listen(port);
```